# How to include a php file from webroot inside a ctp file in cake php?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have a piece of code which doing google login it is given in below. It is in normal php where it includes a file. The code is given below.

```
require 'openid.php';
try {
# Change 'localhost' to your domain name.
$openid = new LightOpenID('http://s396001438.onlinehome.us/test2/');
if(!$openid->mode) {
if(isset($_GET['login'])) {
$openid->identity = 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id';
header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
}
?>
<form action="?login" method="post">
<button>Login with Google</button>
</form>
<?php
} elseif($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
`enter code here`} else {
    echo 'User ' . ($openid->validate() ? $openid->identity . ' has ' : 'has not ') . 'logged in.';
}
}catch(ErrorException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is **totally** wrong.

- Webroot is **the** wrong place for libs like that, it belongs into /app/vendors, load it with App::import(), look it up in book.cakephp.org
- You're not using the FormHelper, by this and very likely without using the Security component the form might be exploitable
- DO NOT use $_GET and $_POST directly, use $this->data & $this->request in 1.3
- I don't know this lib but the whole code looks like a nice violation of the MVC framework. The LightOpenId stuff should be very likely done in a controller and there the exception should be catched and set as an error message to the view. Maybe even better to wrap it in a component.
- Read and more important *understand* the *[MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)* pattern
- Read about the basics of CakePHP and do the blog tutorial

Answer (score 0):

the right place for this code to go is either Vendors or convert it into a plugin (for cakephp 2.0).

Using cakephp 1.3 you should put it in Vendors and folder and do

```
App::import();
```

Please look into the cookbook to see usage examples of the same. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/943/Loading-Vendor-Files

The App class is very useful utility library. http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/933/The-App-Class